# Wordpress: Add Google Tags to website's home page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, google-tag-manager

I want to edit my website's home page.

To add Google Tag `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="************" />`

But I can't find out home page HTML in WordPress. All I see is Wordpress/Elementor page editor, which allows me to edit blocks but not top `<html>` tags.

How can I do that? I don't have CPanel/FireZilla Access.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/

Comment: This plugin will allow you to add VPC's hook without access to files : https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: Is there a way I can see and edit file? There is some `<div>`, where I want to give id attributes, not only hooks/snippets. Example: `<div>` should become `<div id="helloWorld">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fuction.php your theme add this

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'google_verification', 1);
function google_verification() {
    echo '<meta name="google-site-verification" content="************" />', "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in WordPress dashboard Appearance-->Theme editor -->Header.php file(if exists)
copy the code and paste in between   .then update